# Is it possible to personalize eToken PASS?

Tags: authentication

I am wondering if it is possible to personalize an eToken to PASS with the following method:

On the server side we configure a physical device eToken to PASS when it belongs to Mr. Bob.

So when he uses his secretly generated number to login we know that it was Mr. Bob.

What I mean by a "personalized" eToken PASS is that by associating it with a user account ID can it be detected with certainty that the user account ID is bounded to it.

Comment: Even with the [data sheet](https://safenet.gemalto.com/uploadedFiles/Products/Enterprise_Data_Protection/Multi-Factor_Authentication/OTP_Authenticators/eToken_PASS_PB__EN__web.pdf) of a device sold under the name _eToken PASS_, I fail to understand what's asked.

Comment: @fgrieu Well Sorry for my English. I need to know if  Mr.Bob  which provides eToken's device password could be identified. as Mr.Bob. So I assume the range of passwords that generate  eToken's device  must be  associated with Mr.Bob somehow. I assume ot use eToken's device  password to login only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [eToken PASS](https://safenet.gemalto.com/uploadedFiles/Products/Enterprise_Data_Protection/Multi-Factor_Authentication/OTP_Authenticators/eToken_PASS_PB__EN__web.pdf) is a small device that displays, on a LCD display, a One Time Password when a button is pressed. This number depends on an internal key unique to the device, and either time or the index of the keypress, depending on mode. The battery lasts appreciably longer in counter mode. The device has a serial number, sometime printed and/or barcoded on the backside. Often there are contacts used for setup (definition of operating mode, key, time setup), more or less hidden behind a sticker.

From a cryptography standpoint, the OTP is a MAC of the time in some unit (e.g. in minutes or half-minute since a reference) or of a counter, using the device's key.

The number displayed on the LCD can be verified by software on a server, *assumed to know the device's serial number and unique key*. The software has tolerance for (and/or keeps track of) the drift of an individual token's clock, or the state of its counter, in order to avoid reuse of a previous OTP, and (in clock mode only) of one obtained a long time ago. Sometime it is kept track of failed attempts, and the number of consecutive failed attempts limited (perhaps, within a time period). Sometime the OTP verification is performed by a separate device/service.

In practice, somewhat, the serial number gets paired with an account ID in a registration phase. I have often seen this done by the issuer, so that the end user receive his/her token ready to use. Often, the device's key is diversified, that is derived from a master key and device serial number using a [Key Derivation Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function), which conveniently replaces a database of device keys with the single master key.

---

I understand the question as: after registration, can the OTP displayed by the token be used to securely identify a user? The answer is **no**, for the OTP alone; but **yes**, if combined with some other information allowing to obtain the token's serial number, including a user account ID. Importantly, that extra information is static and needs neither be secret nor trusted.

The system requires knowing the token's serial number in order to verify the OTP. The serial number can be keyed-in by the user from a sticker on the back of the token, or found by the server from the user's account ID. The verification also requires the device's key; that is typically stored along the device's serial number, or recomputed from the serial number and a master key using a KDF.